# Change text of a Label in site.master from code-behind

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I've got an asp.net webforms project with a Site.Master page that's ref'd by my content pages.
The header is:
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="JT1.SiteMaster" %>

....

it includes a navbar with a few buttons and a label on the right like so:

```
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Login">Log In | Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><p runat="server" class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                    <label runat="server" id="LoggedInUserID" >Logged Off</label>
                    </p></li>
```

All of the buttons show up and work properly, and the text "Logged Off" appears by default on all
pages that use the master.
From the Login.aspx.cs, I want to change the text of the "LoggedInUserID" label to something
appropriate, like "Welcome, Jim".  This code is the best I've been able to come up with:

```
HtmlControl ctl = Master.FindControl("LoggedInUserID") as HtmlControl;
if (ctl != null) ctl.Attributes["InnerText"] = "Welcome " + firstname;
```

This actually finds the proper control, and I can see in the debugger that its InnerText is, in fact, "Logged Off".  But my assignment to it does NOT work.  No exception, no error, nothing.
I've perused lots of other similar questions and don't see anything I've not tried.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to change the text from Login.aspx? Shouldn't Login.aspx be responsible for logging you in, then redirecting you to another page in your app? And the master page itself be responsible for rendering itself properly based on whether you're logged in or not?

Comment: @Mason - Every page, including the login page, uses the Master to display the navbar at the top.  From what I have gathered, the approach I am using is completely legit.  BUT, you raise an interesting point, that I could just have the Master recognize and display login status itself, without trying to push it from the login page per se.  Thanks for the idea - I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the child page loads first, AND THEN the parent (master) page loads.

So, your code (if on a child page) would run, but THEN the master page loads, and your setting is lost.

However, lets assume we moved the code (and even a test button) to the master page.

When you click on that button, child page load, master page load, your button code runs, label gets set.

But, what happens now if you click on another menu bar item?

Turns out that AGAIN the master page loads. you can think of this as if you navigated to one page, and then navigated back to that page.

As a result, EVEN if you place a button + code in master page to "change" the Label? Well that will at least work + show the change, since master runs AFTER the child page.

However, that control ONLY going to persist now as long as you "stay" on that one master + child page.

This would be no different then if you had a button on the page. Setting label or text box. Such a page can survive post-backs no problem.
(controls have automatic viewstate with runat=server)

However, if we navigate to a new page, and then navigate back (not using back button), then that label setting will be lost (and this is how you have to consider the master page).

So, now that we "fixed" the above setting?

Well, we now have to consider if a new menu bar option is hit and now we navigate to a whole new master/child page.

In this navigation, the master page is re-loaded from start. So, once again, you would have to re-run that code.

Long story short?

You need to move that code into the page-load event of the master page.

I mean, a really "neat-o" kluge when you want to modify/change/update/show/see the main menu bar change?

You can execute (in child page that changed the menu "settings" - note I stated menu settings, since we STILL in theory have to change the mnu bar in master page. So, in this context, we might have changed some setting - but it would have to be session type of deal). Now, how to "see" this updated status/change in the nav bar?
You can do this:

```
response.Redirect("name of current page we on.aspx")
```

That will of course "force" a menu bar refresh. (kind of like hitting a different menu bar option, and then hitting the one we were on).

But, as noted, it only going to see such forced changes if the master page load event "changes" what it was doing in the first place.

(since with runat=server, you get viewstate for that control).

However, the instant you click on another menu item, you have to "consider" this a whole new brand new navigation to that page anyway.

Comment: thanks for that detailed explanation! I did not realize Master gets loaded after the Page-x.   I think I see the path to success here, via the Master PageLoad, so I'll check that out.  I'm thinking that Login.aspx can  stuff info into Session state, then Redirect to another page, at which time Master.PageLoad can pick that up and display it.  Thanks again!  I'll report back on the results!

Comment: It a bit messy, but I guess the rule is that you want such code in master page load to setup the menu bar.  For example I have a "badge" display (just like the one on here for SO showing a number + count beside the message box button in upper right). So to display the "active" projects, that kind of stuff occurs in normal pages (child pages), but I need the menu bar to update. So, the code to count + display active projects as a badge in menu bar had to be moved to master page load

Comment: OK, showing signs of life, but not quite there: after this runs, the navbar label still shows "Logged Off".  IT's like it needs another refresh or ???protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlControl ctl = FindControl("LoggedInUserID") as HtmlControl;
            string username = (string)Context.Session["Username"];
            string firstname = (string)Context.Session["Firstname"];
            string welcome = "Welcome " + firstname;
            if (ctl != null) ctl.Attributes["InnerText"] = welcome;
        }

Comment: BTW, the ctl.InnerText was set to the expected value. :)

Comment: The "another" refresh issue was outlined in my post. If your child page code runs that would "for any" reason need the menu bar to be up-dated? Then you have to re-navagate to the same page to show this change. Also, we assume a "keen" awareness of IsPostBack -- the first page load IsPostBack=False (both master/child). For additional post-backs, both master/child IsPostBack=True. Regardless, if you JUST run code that changes the status of the menu bar (but we all agreeing that master page load will maintains that status), you need the "trick" explained above.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit confused.   At this point, in the Login.aspx.cs when I find that I've got a valid login, I put things into Session vars as I described earlier.  I've then tried a couple different "Response.Redirect"s ... both to same login page, and to a different child page.   The site.master PageLoad (non Postback) code tries to do:if (ctl != null) ctl.Attributes["InnerText"] = welcome;

Comment: but a debugger break at that line, and inspection of ctl.Attributes["InnerText"] shows it to be UNchanged.  I *know* I saw this get changed once before, but now I'm skunked!

Comment: you have to re-execute the code each time on site master page load. Also consider using a asp.net label, and not a html one - it has bult in viewstate and will persist better. however, as I stated, you have to use site master page load event  for this to work.

Comment: I mean, where does the logon page go to after the logon? It no doubt goes to some other page - and no doubt it is a master page, so your code will trigger. I would for testing not test for IsPostBack in the master page load event - just make it the first line of page load in master. The "re-direct" trick is ONLY required if you staying on the same page and not going some other place  (and you need your menu bar to custom update or show new stuff)- and in your case I can't imagine that after logon you staying on the logon page anymore, right? When you move off logon page then menu should update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251972/discussion-between-jim-and-albert-d-kallal).